# PolicyServer.Local Error In PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware When Using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I've set up a Asp.Net Core 2.2 MVC web application with Windows Authentication, and added the PolicyServer.Local code to assist in adding Authorization to the web app.

Whenever it performs an authorization check on a controller action, I get an error...Anyone seen this type of thing before?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "MailAdministrator")]
public IActionResult About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

    return View();
}

Win32Exception: The trust relationship between the primary domain and the 
trusted domain failed
```

System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, out bool someFailed)

Comment: One interesting thing is that If I use a permission instead of a role in the Authorize attribute, it works fine....The problem appears to be role centric.

Comment: Win32Exception:The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed.